# Date comparison using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use the following code to check the date is before today! But when I select today, the condition becomes true!

```
var fromDate = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
var toDate = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
var today = new Date();

if(today >= fromDate || toDate <= today){
    alert('Cannot book dates prior to today.');
    $('#from, #to').val('')
    return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it just for the current state? Not future states?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but don't you want ">=" and "<=" to be just ">" and "<"... seems to me that your code includes today?

Comment: what do you mean by current state? are you referring to the current date? if so, yes! it's only happening for the current date.

Comment: You are missing `;` after `$('#from, #to').val('')`.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up but I don't think that the ; is the issue!

Comment: @RahulDesai http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be something like

```
var fromDate = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
var toDate = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
var today = new Date();
 today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
fromDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
toDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

if(today > fromDate || toDate < today){
    alert('Cannot book dates prior to today.');
    $('#from, #to').val('')
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Still the condition becomes true when I select current date as fromDate

Comment: Then you have to use `&&`. Or `if(!(today > fromDate && toDate < today))` in your case, confused. ;)

Comment: I noticed this in my date variables! today variable contains a full date with the current time and the from date only consists of the date and time in the midnight. is this the issue?

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri Hmm, wait, let me think loud, when you click on "today" what is the time...hmm today 0am, midnight of start of the day or end of the day? Or different in "from" and "to", "from" has start of day, and "to" has end of day? This is the problem why I do not post an answer, I do not know the `datepicker`. ;)

Comment: @dollarvar using && is not possible since, I want to fire the method even if one condition is true!

Comment: @dollarvar There are the values which reside in the vars 

today : Wed Feb 05 2014 11:03:26 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)

fromDate : Wed Feb 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)

Hope you get the idea. btw I'm using the jquery datepicker

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri Yeah, I know the jQuery datepicker, I guessed so, but did not *use* him yet, hmmm, so `today > fromDate` is `true`?